# Dynamically create hrefs that pan to unique Google Map latLng in asynch function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, closures, href

I'm trying to dynamically append hrefs that will, when clicked, pan a Google map to given coordinates. The code below successfully creates href links that pan the map -- but it keeps panning to the location of the most recently created circle.

I added the closure panToCircle, hoping that would preserve the the current coordinates within the enclosed IIFE, but no such luck. What do you think is my best strategy, here? Thanks a ton!

Note: This is all chained from an asynch callback, creating the circle every time a response comes from the server.

```
var text = 'Hello World!';
// Hoisting the panToCircle up here, as Chrome was giving me undefined ref errors when initializing it in linkToCircle.
var panToCircle = function(){};
var rgb = [100,100,100];  
createCircle();

function createCircle(){
    var color = 'RGB(' + rgb.toString() + ')';                    
    var myCircle = initCircle();
    linkToCircle();

    function linkToCircle(){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.innerHTML = text + "<br><br>";
        a.style.color = color;

        panToCircle = function(){
            // Defining center in here, as putting a center in as an argument to the href function reclasses the center as a string, not a latLng
            var center = myCircle.getCenter();
            (function panNow(cen){
                map.panTo(cen);
            })(center);
        }

        a.href = 'javascript:panToCircle();'
        document.getElementById('text-div').appendChild(a);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cool, a really simple fix worked, just had to take a step back from it and consider other options. I formatted a string from the current coordinates and concatenated it into the href value.

```
   function linkToCircle(){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.innerHTML = text + "<br><br>";
        a.style.color = color;

        panToCircle = function(latLng){
          alert(latLng)
          var cen = {'lat': Number(latLng[0]), 'lng': Number(latLng[1])};              
          map.panTo(cen);
        }

        // Just had to do an eval-ish thing to get it to take the current coordinates by 
        // formatting the string correctly, as an array. I had tried something similar
        // before, but it was rejecting the arguments as a comma-separated list. 
        var centerString = center.lat.toString() + ',' + center.lng.toString();
        a.href = 'javascript:panToCircle([' + centerString + ']);'
        document.getElementById('text-div').appendChild(a);

   }
```

Please feel free to respond with an explanation on why my closure attempt failed above. Closures are new to me (I'm new to js in general), would love to learn more. Will accept an answer that explains the closure element to the first post. Thanks!